# Neil Turok's last exercise!

Tags: general-relativity

In the last video of a series of lectures given by Neil Turok on GR in perimeter, he wants to give an exercise. Unfortunately (for us) the students shout, we've already done that. Although he does reveal some of the exercise he has in mind. Can any one help me and tell what the exercise probably is? (It sounds like a well known fact to prove, so you may know about it if you know GR!)

His words go : "show that the maximum proper time exprienced..., sorry? Oh you did that? Oh fine, great, you've done it! So you saw 
$$\frac{\pi r_s}{2}$$ 
right? Ok! great haha don't show! Arright, thank you very much! Ok :)))"

Comment: Link to video ?

Comment: Perhaps he's asking about the maximal survival time for an observer in a Schwarzschild black hole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\pi r_s/2$ is the maximum proper time possible for an observer at the event horizon to fall to the singularity, so this is probably the exercise that Turok had in mind.

The calculation can be found in various sources, but I recommend you read [No Way Back: Maximizing survival time below the Schwarzschild event horizon](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1029v1) by Geraint F. Lewis and Juliana Kwan as this goes into the calculation in some detail.